# Receiving MySQL value to Flash

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I am new to PHP and MySQL but have somehow managed to setup a MySQL guestbook and download counter.

All I want to do is view the value of a specific row i.e. id = 2 and column i.e. downloads in the download_manager table, setup id, FILE, DOWNLOADS

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoader;

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("update.php?xx=1");
var getVariables:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
getVariables.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
getVariables.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
getVariables.load(request);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var downLOADS = urlVariables.decode(event.target.data);
dCounter.condenseWhite = true;
dCounter.textField.opaqueBackground = 0x333333;
dCounter.htmlText = "" + downLOADS;
}

dload01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, dOver);
dload01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, dOut);
dload01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dClick);

function dClick (e:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("download.php?file=temp_01.zip"), '_self');
}
function dOut (e:MouseEvent):void
{
dload01.gotoAndPlay("out");
}
function dOver (e:MouseEvent):void
{
dload01.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
```

the dCounter is the textField

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$body="";
$theQuery = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM download_manager WHERE id = 'xx'");
$thisRow = mysqli_fetch_row($theQuery);

$dloads = $thisRow['DOWNLOADS'];
$body .= '<b><font name="Teen" color="#FFFFFF" size="11">' . $dloads . '</font></b>';
mysqli_close();
echo "returnBody=$body"; 
exit(); 
?>
```

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Any code? What have you tried?

Comment: Update your question to contain the relevant information. You can still edit it. Don't post it in the comments.